# Docker. Ports are not available. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, server, port

**(HTTP code 500) server error - Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:54322 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:54322: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.**

What could be the core problem in my case when I'm trying to run the app which hasn't been touched for several months? When I'm trying to run postgres container i see this notification with error.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fmr9.png)
[Docker container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLHHY.png)

**Here is the instruction:**
Launch
Locally for development

1. Copy app.env.example to app.env. Fill it out
2. At the root, write `docker-compose up`. When changing the `package.json` or `yarn.lock' must be restarted with the` docker-compose up --build`flag for reassembly. To install the new package in`node_modules'.
3. On the local machine, go to the `app` folder, and make a `yarn install` there. This is necessary so that the IDE can prompt. because inside the docker container there is its own folder `node_modules`, which is in no way related to the one that is available on the local machine. This is necessary because the encoder uses Linux, and our local machines may have windows/mac os installed, and they will need different packages.
4. Write code. It is pushed to ports nodejs - 30000, postgres - 54322

If somebody knows a method, please share it, cause it's been a week already since I try to fix this error.

Comment: [this](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/the-engine-node-is-incompatible-with-this-module) is worth checking. Try deleting node_modules/, package-lock.json & yarn.lock then run  `yarn install` again

Comment: @dhiaabenhamadou sadly, but none of it helped. Maybe the problem is with dockerfile?  Maybe I should update the node version in docker? It's just my theory.

Comment: Meanwhile, can you share your Dockerfile? ..(of course, you should hide any sensitive Data you have there)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @dhiaabenhamadou I sucseed in docker-compose up but now have differrent problem with running the postgres container. Seems like some net error, something wrong with my port, but I can't understand what exactly.